¿Por qué la fila se duplica cuando actualizo la tabla?
Estoy haciendo un proyecto, pero note algo extraño, cuando filtro los registros de mi tabla y la actualizo, la fila se repite.
Así se ve la vista normalmente:

Pero cuando la actualizo me repite la fila:

La tabla la actualizo despues de cambiar el estatus. Pero no he encontrado el error o la parte del código que hace eso.
El jTable la inicializo de la siguiente manera:
private DefaultTableModel modeloP;
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter;

private ArrayList<ProveedorMPrima> ListaProveedores = new ArrayList<>();

private void TableActions()
{
    jt_Proveedores.setAutoCreateRowSorter(false);
    modeloP = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Proveedores.getModel();
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modeloP);
    jt_Proveedores.setRowSorter(sorter);
    jt_Proveedores.Tabla = "Proveedores";
}

Y la lleno de la siguiente manera:
private void CargarDatosTabla()
{      
    LimpiartTabla();
            
    ListaProveedores = dProv.getAll(cpt);
    
    if(!ListaProveedores.isEmpty())
    {
        for(ProveedorMPrima p : ListaProveedores)
        {
            Object[] fila = 
            {
                p.getProveedor(),
                p.getNombre(),
                p.getRfc(),
                p.getCp(),
                p.getRazons(),
                p.getPais(),
                p.getEstatus().equals("1")
            };
            
            modeloP.addRow(fila);
        }
    }
}
private void LimpiarTabla()
{
    int filas = jt_Proveedores.getRowCount();

    if(filas > 0)
    {
        for(int i = filas - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            modeloP.remove(i);
        }
     }
}

El sorter lo uso de la siguiente manera en el evento keyRelease de un jTexfield:
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + txt_Buscar.getText(), 1));


Dentro del proceso de carga, tienes LimmpiarTabla, que se supone que hace eso? no mostraste el código.

Si hace lo que se supone, limpiarTabla, inicializaria la lista de proveedores, pero no entiendo por que luego haces un getAll(cpt)

Ya lo puse, identifica la cantidad de registros, si es mayor a 0 entra en un bucle for y elimina los registros de modelo de la tabla

Haces uso de LimpiarTabla() ?

Normalmente hago que se ejecute como en el código que puse aqui, así cada que mando llamar el metodo CargarTabla(), primero se ejecuta el metodo limpiar tabla para vaciar el modelo y despues lo vuelvo a llenar

Luego de hacer dProv.getAll(cpt); haz un print de los datos, y revisa que no haya duplicados.

El problema de los duplicados probablemente se deba a que no estás limpiando correctamente las filas antes de volver a llenar la tabla. En lugar de usar el método modeloP.remove(i) en LimpiarTabla(), prueba algo más directo:
modeloP.setRowCount(0);

Esto elimina todas las filas de una vez, de forma eficiente. También revisa que el método dProv.getAll(cpt) no esté devolviendo datos duplicados.
Asegúrate por último dee no llamar CargarDatosTabla() más veces de las necesarias.

Por ahora lo pude resolver quitando el método de LimpiarTabla, y en su lugar puse las siguientes líneas:
//Si la tabla tiene filas
if(jt_Proveedores.getRowCount() > 0)
{
    //vaciamos el modelo de la tabla
    modeloP.setRowCount(0);
}

